# Formatting JSON in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-web-api2

I'm building web API for Android app in ASP.NET. How can i format JSON to return only part of information but not whole object from database? For example when i want to get all categories and categories have tables of events i want to get only event ID's in this table.

Comment: you can probably query the list of events to get get list of event ID's and then return that as response. Web api by default returns the response in JSON format only

Comment: It got something to do with Navigation properties in Entity, but i can't find the proper property of this property.

Comment: Create own class which contain only information you need. Then fill it with data from database.